# Basic SQL Subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on a project where I am supposed to pull the top 2 Dates of all of my customers last order in MS Access. In the event that there is only one date , it should pull up that single date as well.

```
SELECT Customer_t.Customer_ID, 
Customer_t.Customer_Name, 
Order_t.Order_ID, 
Order_t.Order_Date
FROM Customer_t 
INNER JOIN Order_t 
 ON Customer_t.Customer_ID = Order_t.Customer_ID
WHERE (((Customer_t.Customer_ID)=[Order_t].[Customer_ID]))
```

I am a little new but I am having difficulty following the sub-query information that is currently out on the web.

*I know I am trying to use the TOP 2 statement but I continue to    receive syntax errors or statements that will say the most I can pull    is one item*
.

Any help would be appreciated. I have seen similar questions to this already but I cannot repeat what the answers have recommended

Answer (score 2):

This type of query is a bit tricky in MS Access.  You can't do what you want easily with `JOIN`.  Instead, think of this as filtering.  You want to keep only the two most recent order ids for each customer.

That suggests a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT c.Customer_ID,  c.Customer_Name, o.Order_ID, o.Order_Date
FROM Customer_t as c INNER JOIN
     Order_t as o
     ON c.Customer_ID = o.Customer_ID
WHERE c.Order_ID IN (SELECT TOP 2 o2.Order_Id
                     FROM Order_t as o2
                     WHERE o2.Customer_Id = o.Customer_Id
                     ORDER BY o2.Order_Date, o2.Order_Id
                    );
```

I'm including `Order_id` in the `ORDER BY` so each row has a unique key.  In MS Access, `TOP` really does `TOP WITH TIES`, so it is a good idea to add a unique key if you really want at most 2 rows.

Comment: You are renaming Order_t as o and then again as 02 why do that? t What is the purpose behind renaming the table twice? I  apologize if my question seem elementary

Comment: @XenonArendovich . . . `o` is needed in the outer query to return columns.  `o2` is needed in the subquery to identify the two order ids that you want to keep.